# How to properly do Multiple Command Substitution in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, variables

I am trying to have a variable execute 2 commands when typed in the terminal, namely change to a specific directory and run an executable. However when executed it returns

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

This is how I defined the variable in .bashrc

```
export FOO='cd "/path/to/directory" ; /path/to/executable'
```

When I input this line directly it works fine. So what is the proper way of defining such a variable?

Comment: You have to use `eval`. `eval "$FOO"`

Comment: Why are you doing it as a variable instead of a function?

Comment: I see, that worked thanks.  I am new to Linux and not very proficient in bash.

Comment: Use a function or alias; variables are for data, not commands. Avoid `eval`, it solves some problems but creates others. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score -1):

After the suggestion by Barmer and Gordon and a quick search I managed to achieve the result I wanted using functions.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer